# Дочерний элемент при масштабировании выходит за пределы родительского

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Есть родительский блок (box), в котором находятся дочерние блоки (header, info, etc). Проблема в том, что медиа-запрос при уменьшении размера экрана срабатывает, родительский блок уменьшается, но проблема в том, что дочерние блоки, содержащие текст выходят за пределы родителя. Не получается никак решить проблему, пробовал делать перенос слов в блоках, но не помогает. Прошу помощи)
Песочница и скрин проблемы:

```css
* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
 transition: all .2s;
}

.box {
 position: absolute;
 margin: auto;
 top: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 width: 1010px;
 height: 503px;
 border: 1px solid #d7d7d7;
 background-color: #ffffff;
}

.head {
 position: absolute;
 display: inline-block;
 width: 178px;
 height: 22px;
 top: 94px;
 right: 309px;
 left: 523px;
 bottom: 387px; 
 color: #2f2f2f;
 font-family: "Arial - Bold MT";
 font-size: 23px;
 font-weight: 400;
}

.info {
 position: absolute;
 display: inline-block;
 word-break: break-all;
 width: 393px;
 height: 50px;
 top: 146px;
 right: 93px;
 bottom: 307px;
 left: 524px;
 color: #2f2f2f;
 font-family: "Arial-MT";
 font-size: 15px;
 font-weight: 400;
}

.price {
 position: absolute;
 display: inline-block;
 width: 35px;
 height: 14px;
 top: 251px;
 right: 451px;
 bottom: 238px;
 left: 524px;
 font-family: "Arial-MT";
 font-size: 15px;
 font-weight: 400;
}

.count {
 position: absolute;
 display: inline-block;
 width: 103px;
 height: 28px;
 top: 288px;
 right: 381px;
 bottom: 187px;
 left: 526px;
 color: #2f2f2f;
 font-family: "Arial-MT";
 font-size: 30px;
 font-weight: 400px;

}

.button {
 position: absolute;
 display: inline-block;
 text-align: center;
 width: 252px;
 height: 50px;
 top: 372px;
 right: 327px;
 bottom: 167px;
 left: 526px;
 padding: 16px 39px;
 color: #ffffff;
 font-family: "Arial-MT";
 font-size: 19px;
 font-weight: 400;
 background-color: #ec744a;
}

#img {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 376px;
 height: 375px;
 padding-left: 48px;
 padding-top: 64px;
 padding-bottom: 64px;
 padding-right: 586px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 991px) {
 .box {
  width: 600px;
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Карточка товара</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="box">
  <div id="img"><img src="img/img_1.png"></div>
  <div class="head"><span>Наушники Beats</span></div> 
  <div class="info">Накладные наушники с микрофоном, поддержка iPhone, регулятор громкости, разъём mini jack 3.5 mm, длина провода 1.361 м, вес 205 г, складная конструкция</div>
  <div class="price">Цена</div>
  <div class="count">1 999 р.</div>
  <div class="button"><span>Положить в корзину</span></div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]CSS:

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    transition: all .2s;
}

.box {
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 1010px;
    height: 503px;
    border: 1px solid #d7d7d7;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

.head {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 178px;
    height: 22px;
    top: 94px;
    right: 309px;
    left: 523px;
    bottom: 387px; 
    color: #2f2f2f;
    font-family: "Arial - Bold MT";
    font-size: 23px;
    font-weight: 400;
}

.info {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    word-break: break-all;
    width: 393px;
    height: 50px;
    top: 146px;
    right: 93px;
    bottom: 307px;
    left: 524px;
    color: #2f2f2f;
    font-family: "Arial-MT";
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 400;
}

.price {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 35px;
    height: 14px;
    top: 251px;
    right: 451px;
    bottom: 238px;
    left: 524px;
    font-family: "Arial-MT";
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 400;
}

.count {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 103px;
    height: 28px;
    top: 288px;
    right: 381px;
    bottom: 187px;
    left: 526px;
    color: #2f2f2f;
    font-family: "Arial-MT";
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 400px;

}

.button {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    width: 252px;
    height: 50px;
    top: 372px;
    right: 327px;
    bottom: 167px;
    left: 526px;
    padding: 16px 39px;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: "Arial-MT";
    font-size: 19px;
    font-weight: 400;
    background-color: #ec744a;
}

#img {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 376px;
    height: 375px;
    padding-left: 48px;
    padding-top: 64px;
    padding-bottom: 64px;
    padding-right: 586px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 991px) {
    .box {
        width: 600px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Уменьшайте ширину блока с картинкой и блоков с текстом или переносите информацию под картинку

Comment: я попробовал в [песочнице](https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/BGavmr) сделать этот пример ... с медиа запросами

Comment: А Вы стили просто из фотошопа скопировали, да? )

Comment: С макета брал, но только размеры и шрифты)